# sphinx filter by relation column

Tags: sphinx, relation, sphinxql

i have 2 tables:
apartment
building

each apartment have building_id

apartment has "floor" column, where is stored apartment floor.
each building has "totalFloors" column, where is stored total floors(for example, current apartment is 3 of 9 floor)

i need to filter apartments like "where apartment floor is not last floor".

How can i do this?

Im using SphinxQL.

Comment: What does "not last floor" actully mean? Top floor, ie floor = totalFloors?

Comment: last floor = totalFloors.
if totalFloors = 9, then..last floor is 9

Comment: so.. where should be something like where('floor', '!=', 'totalFloors')

Comment: So surely you now have your answer `WHERE floor < totalFloors`?

Comment: you cant write in sphinx like that...........

Comment: ok, just rewrite it a bit `SELECT *,totalFloors - floor AS filter FROM index WHERE filter > 0;`

Comment: please, write your answer as "answer" so i could give you reputation. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the comments, but

```
SELECT *,totalFloors - floor AS filter FROM index WHERE filter > 0;
```

should do it :)